# Passing data from platform specific page to PCL in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I've created a platform specific page using PageRenderer and I need to pass data back from this page when a button is clicked.

I've looked at using the DependancyService but all I can find is to call a method in the platform project from the PCL, I need to do the opposite, is this possible?
Or would I be better advised to look at using traditional Event - EventHandler, is this the preferred approach in Xamarin or is there a better way to handle this in Xamarim.Forms?

The data is need to pass back is an object;

```
public class CallAcknowledged
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CallAcknowledged { get; set; }
    public byte[] Signature { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can declare public var in `App.xaml.cs` class `public static List<string> Mylist;` than access it in android project  `var data = App.Mylist;`

Comment: You can just use `Element` object to call the methods on `CustomPage`

Comment: There is also the messaging center: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center

Comment: @MarkusMichel, thanks for the pointer to the messagingcentre. I'm able to send ad subscribe to a message within the same project, but if I subscribe (in the PCL project)  to the message that is sent from the UWP project nothing happens. Is there anything that I'm missing? All help appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post the code you use for subscribing and sending the messages? Maybe in a new question and link it here.

In most cases the messaging center doesn't work when the according classes haven't been set properly or if the differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to find the answer in this post from @AlessandroCaliaro on the Xamarin Forum
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/70235/xamarin-forms-messagingcenter-between-two-differents-pages-projects

I needed to do use the PCLProjectName.App as the source of the message and it works a dream.

Sender

```
MessagingCenter.Send<MyMobileApp.App, string>((MyMobileApp.App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "Acknowledged", fullNameValue);
```

Subscriber

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MyMobileApp.App, string>((App)Application.Current, "Acknowledged", (sender, arg) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Full Name : " + arg);
        });
```

Thanks to @MarkusMichel for pointing me in the right direction